# Retrieve Array values from the Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I do a `console.log(item)` to the item which i got received from a service it shows the following. It prints as a object and as i can understand it includes a array. How can I retrieve the "Generic" as the value. I am using typescript as the language.

```
 Object {results: Array(1)}
 results    :    Array(1)
 0    :    Object
 Value    :    "Generic"
 __metadata    :    Object
 __proto__    :    Object
 length    :    1
 __proto__    :    Array(0)
 __proto__    :    Object
```

I have used the stingify option and adding the output below

```
 {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "http://Test:30000/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TemplatesModality('Generic')",
                    "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.TemplatesModalityValue"
                },
                "Value": "Generic"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Now do `console.log(JSON.stringify( obj, 0, 4 ))` and post the result of that instead, so we can read it

Comment: {
    "results": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "uri": "http://Test:30000/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TaskTemplatesModality('Generic')",
                "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.TaskTemplatesModalityValue"
            },
            "Value": "Generic"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: So your `item` is an object with the `results` key (`item.results`). The value for that key is an array, and the first item in that array (`item.results[0]`) is an object with 2 keys, one of which is `Value` (`item.results[0].Value`).

Comment: Thanks. you thought me how it should be read. Works

Answer (score 1):

Super simple!

You are accessing the first item (0th in fact) hence:

results[0] is what you need

Comment: @SPKan what do you get when console.log(result[0]) ?

Comment: @SPKan you can also JSON.parse() it if that’s easier !